# Conic with only two real points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quadratics, projective-space

I'm trying to think of an example of an irreducible conic in the projective plane over the complex numbers such that it has only two real points and I am having difficulty creating one. Is this even possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Sketch : We are interested in the intersection $C \cap \overline{C}.$ This is $4$ since both $C$ and $\overline{C}$ are equal to $2[L]$ where $[L] \in H_2(\Bbb P^2, \Bbb Z)$ is the class of a line. If you want exactly $2$ this means that $C, \overline{C}$ should be tangent at 2 points. However, a symmetry argument should show that if a curve and its conjugate are tangent at a point, the intersection multiplicity is $>2$, which leads to a contradiction. But this is not very precise so far, I can try to formalize it more later.

Comment: Wow. I did not imagined that you need such "heavy" tools to show it isn't possible. Anyway once you formalized it, I will ask about some of the technicalities. Thanks for the sketch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach outlined in the comments should work, however here is a simpler proof, based on two lemmas which I'll leave as an exercise :-)

1) Let $C$ be a complex projective curve. If $p \in \Bbb RP^2$ is an isolated point of $\Bbb R(C)$, then $p$ is a singular point of $C$.

2) A reduced conic curve has at most a single singular point.

**Remark** : We notice that a conic is irreducible if and only if it is smooth. This means that in your case, you can't even find a smooth complex conic with a single real point. All conics with a unique real point have an equation $\ell \overline{\ell} = 0$ for some complex (with at least a non-real coefficient) linear form $\ell$, and $p = \ell \cap \overline{\ell}$.

Answer (score 3):

An irreducible (=smooth) conic is rational over a field $k$ if and only if it has a rational point over $k$. (Proof: one direction is clear. For the converse, use stereographic projection.)

Hence the set of $\mathbf R$-points of a smooth conic over $\mathbf R$ is either empty or infinite.

Comment: sorry but what does it mean that the curve is rational over the field $k$? Does it mean that all the points on the curve are rational over $k$? If so, then your last sentence just says that either the $\mathbb R$-points all the points of the curve or it is empty. I understand what it means for it having rational point over $k$ but Im not sure about the other term.

Comment: "Rational over $k$" means that there is a birational map $C \dashrightarrow \mathbf P^1$ that is defined over $k$ --- in other words, it is given by polynomials with coefficients in $k$.